# backslash in single quotes

Tags: zsh, backslash, quote

I am using zsh. And I thought "\t" and '\t' should behave differently.

But when I test with following:

```
$ a="\t"

$ b='\t'

$ [[ $a == $b ]] && echo "equal"
equal
```

It seems that backslash behaves the same way no matter single quoted or double.

How to preserve the literal value of backslash then?

Comment: `\t` is special only in ANSI-C quoting, i.e., `$'\t'`.

Comment: As for the last question, you are interpreting it wrong. Backslash is literal in both of your versions.

Comment: I see. so \t is only interpreted when echo is executed while if using $'\t' it is already interpreted before fed into echo?

Comment: `$'\t'` is basically equivalent to a literal tab character, except that it's quoted, so it won't be treated as a word splitter and won't get stripped out by word splitting.